# Cross-platform data visualization software? (Preferably HTML/JS)

Tags: php, html, graph, visualization, data-visualization

I am looking for cross-platform data visualization solution.

It should ideally work in web browsers and by extension on Android and iOS devices.

To go into more detail, I'd like for the server side to be able to accept data via HTTP POSTs (XML, JSON, etc), and then allow for themeable output of these data via widgets (Drupal-like) such as meters, graphs, plain text etc.

The data types should be configurable and easily created/modified.

Here is a quick example:
I want to show temperature from a bunch of sensors as a graph. The sensors can POST the data to a main server and the server can then be called from a browser to display a chewed-up and configurable graph.

Thanks for your input guys!

Answer (score 0):

A little searching on google would yield a lot of libraries, My favorite being a html5 one called Rgraph http://www.rgraph.net/

High charts is another excellent solution. http://www.highcharts.com/

These are both html5 based.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

However, I was looking for a solution where I could also get backend server code to provide the functionality in my question regarding receiving data (via POST), saving it (MySQL or similar) and then outputting it (ie, via a template language).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the combination of google spreadsheet for the DB/backend and Google Visualization for the frontend visualization.

Google GData API has a nice set of client libraries that make writing POST data into Google Spraedsheet a very simple task. Check out: http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#CreatingListRows

```
ListEntry newEntry = new ListEntry();
newEntry.getCustomElements().setValueLocal(tag, value);
ListEntry insertedRow = service.insert(listFeedUrl, newEntry);
```

On the other end, It is rather easy to use the JavaScript libraries of Google Visualization to extract and present data from a published spreadsheet. It has a wide range of widgets ready to use. If you are missing any specific widget, you can use any JS library with some manipulation of the JSON data.

For simple example on the ability to turn a Google Spreadsheet to a live chart check: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets.html#Google_Spreadsheets_as_a_Data_Source